# Struct as a function type

Tags: c, struct, typedef, declaration

I want to call a object from a struct made in a header in which i have a few data types , let me clear the things up.`ft_stock_par.h` is the name of the header.

```
typedef struct s_stock_par
{
    int size_param;
    char *copy;
}   t_stock_par;
```

and then i have the main function from which i want to call the object `t_stock_par` , how can I do so? When I am trying to call from a function with the object like this `t_stock_par.size_param` i get an error `error: expected identifier or '('`

Comment: Your question needs more context. Please show the relevant parts of `main`

Comment: You cannot call objects in C.  Only functions can be called, and you have not presented one.  Beyond that, you have not presented enough code for us to determine what you're actually asking.  Generally, we want a [mcve] to work with.

Answer (score 4):

In this declaration

```
typedef struct s_stock_par
{
    int size_param;
    char *copy;
}   t_stock_par;
```

`t_stock_par` is not an object of type `struct s_stock_par`. It is an alias for this type.

You need to define an object of the type either removing the typedef keyword like

```
struct s_stock_par
{
    int size_param;
    char *copy;
}   t_stock_par;
```

In this case `t_stock_par` will be indeed an identifier of an object of type `struct s_stock_par`.

Or using a separate declaration of the object

```
typedef struct s_stock_par
{
    int size_param;
    char *copy;
}   t_stock_par;

t_stock_par obj;
```